# Azure DevOps Custom Page for Requesting / Tracking Features or Bugs

Tags: php, html, node.js, azure, azure-devops

I'm new to using AzureDevOps to handle my team's development needs. Currently I'm faced with the question of how are we going to gather the requirements, change requests, suggestions or bug reports from the end users of our products, that are either deployed or under development.

My idea is to have a simple page that is linked with our Azure DevOps account, which can simply retrieve the list of projects, to help the end user set the category, and then simply email the request to one of the developers to be handled manually. Our end users are limited so this is not an issue of being flooded.

I've search google and others for a template / working example of such page to help me build it quicker, as I'm also very limited on time.

I'm sure someone has done this before. It's just a simple request page connected to DevOps.

Asking about Azure DevOps hosted on Microsoft cloud, with 5 active developer accounts working on 5 different projects. We also use Sharepoint and AzureAD for the company's internal use, and would like to limit the requests to only come from company employees. I tried looking this up, but couldn't find anything "ready made".

Comment: Those who are down voting this question, I would appreciate some feedback to know what I could've done better when posting it.

Comment: i'm not sure why you got downvoted, but I do not understand the question. why dont you use internal azure devops ways of doing that? bugs\tasks\stories\etc?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The idea is we want to have a simple portal for non-technical users to input their requests / issues. As I mentioned, I'm new to DevOps, but I do see it has APIs which can be used to build a web page for gathering such information.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1, but you should probably just use azure boards. its meant for that exactly

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem where we wanted to let people access parts of ADO who dont have an Azure AD account. We need this because we are a large corporation with slow and complicated Active Directory processes...
I asked on server fault and found a little service called TicketStudio in the Marketplace that works good for us: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/aveyaramrsoftwaregbr1612902674653.ticket_studio?tab=Overview